# lynx cronjob called but HTTP request not sent

Tags: php, linux, cron, lynx

I am running a cronjob every 30 minutes from my shared hosting to another of my ec2 server using the following command:-

`0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/lynx http://qwerty.com/crons/myCron.php`

The cron job does run every 30 minutes based on the emails I am receiving from the Cron Daemon. But then the PHP file seems to be called sometimes only. I noticed that it's only successful when the HTTP request is sent in the Cron Daemon email I receive.

Examples are shown below:-

**Unsuccessful Attempts**

```
 Your Terminal type is unknown!

 Enter a terminal type: [vt100] 
TERMINAL TYPE IS SET TO vt100
(B)0[1;24r[m[?7h[?1h=[H[J[21B[0;7mGetting http://qwerty.com/crons/myCron.php[m
[0;7mLooking up qwerty.com[m[K
[0;7mMaking HTTP connection to qwerty.com[m

[24;1H
[?1l>
```

**Successful Attempts**

```
 Your Terminal type is unknown!

 Enter a terminal type: [vt100] 
TERMINAL TYPE IS SET TO vt100
(B)0[1;24r[m[?7h[?1h=[H[J[21B[0;7mGetting http://qwerty.com/crons/myCron.php[m
[0;7mLooking up qwerty.com[m[K
[0;7mMaking HTTP connection to qwerty.com[m
[0;7mSending HTTP request.[m             [22;22H
[0;7mHTTP request sent; waiting for response.[m

[24;1H
[?1l>
```

How can I make sure that the HTTP request is sent each time the cron daemon runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try forcing a dump however this will also dump all the HTML from the page.. Might not be applicable. `-dump` dumps the formatted output of the default document or one specified on the command line to standard out. Under UNIX this can be used in the following way:

`lynx -dump http://qwerty.com/crons/myCron.php`

Or

```
/usr/bin/lynx -mime_header -dump http://qwerty.com/crons/myCron.php
```

Alternatively you could try wget with several tries to ensure full response ..

```
/usr/bin/wget −r −−tries=10 http://qwerty.com/crons/myCron.php
```

Again you could try cURL :

```
curl http://qwerty.com/crons/myCron.php
```

Any of these options viable for you ?

Comment: hello thanks for getting back. Will try dumping the mime_header to see if I can get more information and also see if curl is available to me.

Comment: not very keen in using wget though because I only want the cron to run once and only once every 30 minutes.

Comment: @user1258600 you can still use wget.. The cron controls when the command takes place. Just remove the r and tries params

Comment: after monitoring for a few days, curl seems to have solved my problem. thanks so much!